# Variable name in the method of ColdFusion Object

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to set a variable in a cffunction.

The result is this:

```
<cfset local.layouts.appLayout = '../../app/layouts' & local.appController.new()>
```

The above code works. In the local.layouts.appLayout structure it assigns the return of the new method in the appControler. That is what I need it to do.

My problem is that I need to dynamically assign the method portion of that statement. I have another variable coreRoute.action that equals "new" in that function but I cannot seem to get the syntax right.

I have tried this:

```
<cfset local.layouts.appLayout = '../../app/layouts' & local.appController.coreRoute.action()>
```

That does not work and I can see why. I have also tried this:

```
<cfset local.layouts.appLayout = '../../app/layouts' & local.appController & #coreRoute.action# & '()'>
```

I have tried many variations of this syntax and I just cannot get it right.

Anyone have any ideas about how to do this. I am stuck.

Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE: With Todd Sharp's help I ended up using this and it worked great:

```
<cfinvoke component="#local.appController#" method="#coreRoute.action#" returnvariable="local.act">

            <cfset local.layouts.appLayout = '../../app/layouts' & local.act>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  What do you get if you do a <cfdump var="#local.appController.coreRoute.action()#" />?  Are you sure that local.appController.coreRoute.action() is returning a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look into using `<cfinvoke>` for dynamic method invocation.  Try a Google search for "coldfusion dynamic method invocation" - here's one of the top results:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1320-ColdFusion-CFInvoke-Eliminates-The-Need-For-Evaluate-When-Dynamically-Executing-User-Defined-Functions.htm

Comment: That worked. I should have thought about using cfinvoke. I have recently starting trying to use createObject as much as possible but in this case cfinvoke got the job done. Thanks for the help and oh I used to always read your blog. Good stuff. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

In addition, if you want to do it entirely in script, you can, using this approach:

```
dynFn = this["foo" & bar];
dynFn(stuff);
```

This is in a cfc, if you're doing it from outside the cfc or not using a cfc at all, just change "this" to wherever your method is.

Comment: +1 Thanks @AdamTuttle. This really helped me .. I really did not want to resort to `EVALUATE()`. Was kinda wishing that I  could do it all in one step `this["foo" & bar]( stuff )` like in JS ... nevertheless I would take this any day over `EVALUATE()`. Ciao :)